# ¿Por qué me sale el siguiente error cuando hago "git push origin pollito"?

Tags: git, github

Aclaro: Pollito es la rama con los commits que deseo hacer push al repositorio en github.

Cuando intento hacer:

`git push origin pollito`

No puedo subirla a mi repositorio que clone con un `fork` en `github`.

> Nota: Ya clone localmente el repositorio con el comando:
>
> `git clone <repo>`

**¿Por qué me sale este error?**:

```
David@LAPTOP-7ADS00AA MINGW64 /d/practica_git/pru-git (pollito) $ git push origin pollito Counting objects: 3, done. Delta compression using up to 4 threads.

Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done. Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 389 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done. Total 3 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0) remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (1/1), completed with 1 local object. 

To https://github.com/DavHuay/pru-git.git  ! [remote rejected] pollito -> pollito (permission denied) error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/DavHuay/pru-git.git'
```

Comment: `permission denied` tu usuario no tiene permisos suficientes para pushear o para crear un nuevo branch.

Answer (score 0):

Recomiendo usar:

```
git push -u origin master
```

en tu caso:

```
git push -u origin pollito
```

Esto establecería una relación de seguimiento entre su rama pollito local y su rama remota.

También puedes revisar "[Why do I need to explicitly push a new branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17096311/why-do-i-need-to-explicitly-push-a-new-branch/17096880#17096880)".